# Merging rows with the same date in a Matlab table

Tags: matlab, merge, dataset, unique

I'm writing this post in the hope that someone can help me out with a little problem that requires a good solution. I have a table with the following structure:

> column1 = datenum | column2 = country | column3 = value1 | column4 =
>   value2

Let's say I load the following dataset (I manually added the first column to better show you the rows offsets and should not be considered as part of the dataset):

```
1   736561  'USA'       2752    251
2   736561  'USA'       184     53
3   736561  'USA'       40      0
4   736572  'England'   1       0
5   736573  'USA'       1       0
6   736575  'USA'       1       0
7   736576  'England'   1       0
8   736577  'USA'       2       0
9   736580  'USA'       1       1
10  736581  'USA'       1       0
11  736582  'USA'       1       0
12  736599  'USA'       1       0
13  736619  'USA'       5       0
14  736619  'France'    1       1
15  736683  'USA'       1       0
```

Now, what I need to to is to merge together the rows with the same date. As you can see, this is the case for the rows in the intervals 1:3 and 13:14. I have to do this following a few simple criteria:

- if the country in the duplicate rows is always the same, the final row should still show that country, otherwise it must show "Multiple";
- value1 and value2 of the final row must be the sum of value1 and value2 of the duplicate rows.

Following those criteria, the table in the above example should become (once again, the first column is here in order to simplify data visualization and should not be taken into account by the code):

```
1   736561  'USA'       2976    304
2   736572  'England'   1       0
3   736573  'USA'       1       0
4   736575  'USA'       1       0
5   736576  'England'   1       0
6   736577  'USA'       2       0
7   736580  'USA'       1       1
8   736581  'USA'       1       0
9   736582  'USA'       1       0
10  736599  'USA'       1       0
11  736619  'Multiple'  6       1
12  736683  'USA'       1       0
```

Comment: I don't know if I'll ever be able to solve (nicely) such a problem, but I'd like to ask you a question nonetheless: can a date repeat after a new date has appeared? In other words, are the "same dates" always consequential?

Comment: Yes, since the dataset is sorted by the first column (date) in ascending order. I'm wondering wheter this kind of filtering could be implemented in an easier way during the data parsing routine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After many debugging sessions, I came up with this solution:

```
data = cell2table(data,'VariableNames',{'Date','Country','Value1','Value2'});

[dat_uni,~,dat_idx] = unique(data.Date);

[cty_uni,~,cty_idx] = unique(data.Country);
cty_uni = [cty_uni; 'Multiple'];

cty_tmp = accumarray(dat_idx,cty_idx,[max(dat_idx) 1],@(x) {unique(x)});
mult = cellfun(@(x) length(x) > 1,cty_tmp);
cty_tmp{mult} = max(cty_idx) + 1;
cty_tmp = cat(1,cty_tmp{:});

data_new = table(dat_uni,cty_uni(cty_tmp),accumarray(dat_idx,data.Value1),accumarray(dat_idx,data.Value2));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
clear;clc;close all

datenum = [736561,736561,736561,736572,736573,736575,736576,736577,736580,736581,736582,736599,736619,736619,736683];
country = {'USA'    ,'USA'    ,'USA'    ,'England','USA'    ,'USA'    ,'England','USA'    ,'USA'    ,'USA'    ,'USA'    ,'USA'    ,'USA'    ,'France' ,'USA'    };
val1 = [2752, 184 , 40  , 1   , 1   , 1   , 1   , 2   , 1   , 1   , 1   , 1   , 5   , 1   , 1   ];
val2 = [251, 53, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0];

T = table(int32(datenum'),country',val1',val2','VariableNames',{'datenum' 'country' 'val1' 'val2'})
clearvars -except T

ind = find([1;diff(discretize(T.datenum,[unique(T.datenum);max(unique(T.datenum))+1]))]);
datenum = T.datenum(ind);
country = cell(length(ind),1);
[val1,val2] = deal(zeros(length(ind),1));
for ii = 1:length(ind)
    if ii == length(ind)
        grpind = ind(ii):ind(end);
    else
        grpind = ind(ii):(ind(ii+1)-1);
    end
    cc = T.country(grpind);
    if length(unique(cc))~=1
        cc = 'Multiple';
    else
        cc = cc{1};
    end
    country{ii} = cc;
    val1(ii) = sum(T.val1(grpind));
    val2(ii) = sum(T.val2(grpind));
end

S = table(int32(datenum),country,val1,val2,'VariableNames',{'datenum' 'country' 'val1' 'val2'})
```

Output:

```
T = 

    datenum     country     val1    val2
    _______    _________    ____    ____

    736561     'USA'        2752    251 
    736561     'USA'         184     53 
    736561     'USA'          40      0 
    736572     'England'       1      0 
    736573     'USA'           1      0 
    736575     'USA'           1      0 
    736576     'England'       1      0 
    736577     'USA'           2      0 
    736580     'USA'           1      1 
    736581     'USA'           1      0 
    736582     'USA'           1      0 
    736599     'USA'           1      0 
    736619     'USA'           5      0 
    736619     'France'        1      1 
    736683     'USA'           1      0 


S = 

    datenum     country      val1    val2
    _______    __________    ____    ____

    736561     'USA'         2976    304 
    736572     'England'        1      0 
    736573     'USA'            1      0 
    736575     'USA'            1      0 
    736576     'England'        1      0 
    736577     'USA'            2      0 
    736580     'USA'            1      1 
    736581     'USA'            1      0 
    736582     'USA'            1      0 
    736599     'USA'            1      0 
    736619     'Multiple'       6      1 
    736683     'USA'            1      0 

>>
```